# Problem in installing NVIDIA Quadro K2100M, on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I have a Dell Precision M4800 with two graphic cards:

- 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
- 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev ff)

My Ubuntu version is 12.04. I am having an issue where the resolution is extremely low, and I cannot change it. I tried to install the NVIDIA graphic card. I went to the NVIDIA website and I found that the version of NVIDIA for my graphic card is 340.96, so I downloaded this version Then I ran these below steps:

1- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

2- reboot the system.

3-  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  +  <kbd>F1</kbd>

4- `sudo service lightdm stops`

5- `cd go/to/the/place/of/nvidia.run`

6- `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96`

7- `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96`

**NOTE**- I faced the error that my graphic card does not support this version but I did not pay attention and continue the installation

8- restart the computer

When the computer booted up, the resolution was at the lowest.

9- I tried to run nvidia x server setting but there is this below error:

`You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run`nvidia-xconfig`as root), and restart the X server.`

So I did this:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Resulting in this:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as
'/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

13- then run this below command to restart the xserver:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

But the system went black with this error:

```
Could not write bytes:Broken pipe
```

And I could not do any thing except shutdown. I would really appreciate it if someone would help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I need to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 does it works there?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the Nvidia graphic cards can be a pain in the butt sometimes.
Here's a solution that work for me running Ubuntu 16.04 (**kernel 4.10**) and 18.04 (**kernel 4.15.0-38 generic**) on a HP Zbook 15 equipted with NVIDIA K2100M.

This is a solution that ***does not*** use the drivers downloaded from the official NVidia website.

After executing the following commands you have to restart your workstation:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

By far this is the most simple and basic way to workaround the problematic drivers.

Usually when I use the X.Org X server (The Nouveau drivers), my resolution drops down to something close to 320x240.

Using Nividia-410 or Ndivia-394 causes strange screen ripples (or fluctuations) on the left hand side of the display.

The only negative thing of running a Nvidia-340 driver with a 4.15 kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 is that I cannot change the screen brightness, therefore you've got to use another piece of software (or night mode) if you are an owl like me. 
Nvidia-340 works smooth as hell on Ubuntu 16.04 though - all the functionality is available and there are no glitches.

Answer (score 0):

Jack Doe's solution no longer works (at least not for me).

I have an HP ZBook 15 G2 with NVidia Quadro K2100M running Ubuntu 23.04. It seems that no matter what driver I use or where I get it from (and believe me, I've tried everything), no nvidia drivers work; only x.org drivers work. If anyone tries nvidia drivers and their computers don't work here's how to get out of the mess:

1. Get into *Recovery Mode*.
2. Enable networking.
3. `apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*`
4. `apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
5. `reboot`