# Crashed my Laptop by trying to install graphic cards driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, xserver

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W540 with an Nvidia Quadro K2100M and an internal graphics chip. When playing games the graphics card didn't seem to be recognized and only the chip was beeing used so I tried to install the driver from the nvidia homepage but failed. This however didn't seem to do any harm and the computer worked without a problem. Today I followed this tutorial: [Problem in installing NVIDIA Quadro K2100M, on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706808/problem-in-installing-nvidia-quadro-k2100m-on-ubuntu-12-04)
But now my laptop won't even show anything on the screen. From what I see I think I messed up the xserver but I have no idea how to fix this. When I start the laptop there is only a blinking line on a black screen. The laptop uses 20.04 lts

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: It's best if you install Nvidia drivers *during system installation* by selecting the options for 3rd party proprietary drivers and download updates while installing. After the fact, the easiest way to install Nvidia drivers is with the single command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.  Manual installation of drivers from Nvidia's website is not suggested and having attempted so, that may be difficult to recover from. It seems like you had problems before you even started. At this point it may be prudent to reinstall the OS. I suggest not following guides/instructions that are 10 years old.

Comment: Don't you think there is a way back? The problems occured after executing this commands: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau. There must be a way just to reinstall the xserver. The previous installation of the drivers from nvidia website didn't seem to do any harm

Comment: There's always a way back, but sometimes it takes less time to reinstall the system than it does to first figure out a solution then implement it. From your description, it seems highly likely that's the case. Especially since you had preexisting problems there's probably not a single fix. You only need to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. That's it. And you only have to do that if you don't install during system installation which is preferred. It seems like you currently have mismatched pieces of driver versions from attempting to install it multiple ways. That's not easy to clean up.